# Show and Hide only one <div> using jQuery .hide/.show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The `.show` and `.hide` jQuery code works for every `<span>` with the class `.q_open` and `q_close`. I'm well aware that my because all my `<div>` tags have the class of `.answer` so they will show and hide both answers when I click on any `<span>`. Is there a way to reference only one `<div class=".answer">` when clicking on that `<span>` tag rather than giving each `<div>` a different `class`? Thanks!

The JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".q_open").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(".answer").show();
        });
      })
      $(".q_close").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(".answer").hide();
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

The HTML code:

```
<h2 class="question">
          Q1: (the first question)
          <span class="q_open"></span>
          <span class="q_close"></span>
        </h2>
        <div class="answer" style="display: none;">
          This should only open when clicked by the <span class="q_open"> for Q1.
        </div>
        <h2 class="question">
          Q2: (the second question)
          <span class="q_open"></span>
          <span class="q_close"></span>
        </h2>
        <div class="answer" style="display: none;">
          <p>
           This should only open when clicked by the <span class="q_open"> for Q2.
          </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: This html is not properly balanced.There is no closing tag for span class="q_open" .Can you please edit that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for some sort of accordion. For that, you need to target the exact HTML element to open or close.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".q_open").click(function() {
    // Select the related target to open
    $(this).closest("h2").next(".answer").slideDown();
  });

  $(".q_close").click(function() {
    // Select the related target to close
    $(this).closest("h2").next(".answer").slideUp();
  });
});
```

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/1xydbj22/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).find('.answer').show()
```

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".q_open").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(this).find('.answer').show();
        });
      })
      $(".q_close").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(this).find('.answer').hide();
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace class with id

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $("#q1_open").click(function() {
      $("#answer1").show();
  });
 $("#q2_open").click(function() {
      $("#answer2").show();
  });
  $(".q_close").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $("#answer1").hide();
      $("#answer2").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to find first element traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.

```js
$('.q_open').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.question').next(".answer").show();
});
$(".q_close").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.question').next(".answer").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="question">
          Q1: (the first question)
          <span class="q_open">Open</span>
          <span class="q_close">Close</span>
        </h2>
<div class="answer" style="display: none;">
  This should only open when clicked by the <span class="q_open"> for Q1.</span>
</div>
<h2 class="question">
          Q2: (the second question)
          <span class="q_open">Open</span>
  <span class="q_close">Close</span>
  </h2>
<div class="answer" style="display: none;">
  <p>
    This should only open when clicked by the <span class="q_open"> for Q2.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```